# Autofac throws File Not Found exception when registering Moq instance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-store-apps, moq, autofac

I have created a Windows 8.1 App Store Unit Test project, added Moq and Autofac and tried to register a `Mock<IAccountService>` with Autofac. When I invoke `RegisterInstance(serviceMock.Object)` it Autofac throws a `File Not Found` exception

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    Task<OperationResult> CreateAccount(User user, string password, string passwordConfirmation);

    Task<OperationResult<User>> Signin(string username, string password);
}
```

I set up my Mock with

```
// Set up our mocked repositories and services
var accountServiceMock = new Mock<IAccountService>();
accountServiceMock
    .Setup(service => service.CreateAccount(
        It.IsAny<User>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((User user, string password, string passwordConfirmation) =>
        {
            var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<OperationResult>();
            taskCompletion.SetResult(new OperationResult(true));
            return taskCompletion.Task;
        });

accountServiceMock
    .Setup(service => service.Signin(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string username, string password) =>
        {
            var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<OperationResult<User>>();
            taskCompletion.SetResult(
                new OperationResult<User>(true, new User { Username = username }));

            return taskCompletion.Task;
        });
```

When I register the mock with Autofac, the exception is thrown

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Exception thrown here.
builder.RegisterInstance(accountServiceMock.Object).As<IAccountService>();
IContainer container = builder.Build();
```

If I take this code and build a standard, non-App Store unit test project around it, the unit test runs without a problem and the builder registers the mock instance.

I want to also point out that I can use RegisterType().As(); without any issues. I can also use `RegisterInstance` with a concrete, non-mocked, object without any exceptions.

Is there something I'm missing with this in a Windows 8.1 project?

**Exception**

```
[System.IO.FileNotFoundException]   
{"Could not load file or assembly 'ISymWrapper, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.":"ISymWrapper, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)\r\n
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)\r\n   
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)\r\n   
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)\r\n   
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)\r\n   
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.LoadISymWrapper()\r\n   
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n   
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n   
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.CreateModule(Boolean signStrongName)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.ObtainDynamicModuleWithWeakName()\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.ObtainDynamicModule(Boolean isStrongNamed)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter.CreateTypeBuilder(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces, TypeAttributes flags, Boolean forceUnsigned)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces, TypeAttributes flags, Boolean forceUnsigned)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces, TypeAttributes flags)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.ClassEmitter..ctor(ModuleScope modulescope, String name, Type baseType, Type[] interfaces)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.BuildClassEmitter(String typeName, Type parentType, Type[] interfaces)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.BuildClassEmitter(String typeName, Type parentType, IList interfaceList)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GenerateCode(Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)\r\n   
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, IInterceptor[] interceptors)\r\n   
at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0()\r\n   
at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)\r\n   
at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()\r\n   
at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()\r\n   
at Mobile.Windows.Shared.Tests.Bootstrapper.Setup()
```

Comment: FWIW I got this rather ominous error message when installing Moq on a Windows 8.1 app project via NuGet: `install-package : Could not install package 'Moq 4.2.1409.1722'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Comment: Yeah I get that with the app project, but this is a Windows 8.1 app Unit Test project. Adding the NuGet package to it does not present that error.

Comment: I assume this is still the reason why. The ISymWrapper file it is looking for is part of .NET but not included in the mobile  framework.

Comment: Sounds about right - [this link is dated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx) but it looks like ISymwrapper wasn't supported on the .Net Client profile 4 years back, so might be the case with Mobile ("Black Assembly") :(

Comment: This is definitely an issue with Moq and dynamic proxy stuff in the unit tests, not something with Autofac. It just happens to be surfacing when you're using it in conjunction with Autofac is all.

Answer (score 2):

I just posted an answer to another question that may help you. It will give you a link to an alternate mocking framework that can easily be used with Windows Store Apps.

I'm currently using it with Unity as DI container and Prism.

[Telerik JustMock answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27998197/1303737)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely grab a copy and check it out.

Comment: For now, I just see one little problem: I can't have AssertSet to work as intended...

Comment: I usually use the standard Assert methods and not any that ship with the mocking frameworks, unless I need to verify method invocation